# OC4, Journal 320rc - product dynamic tabs

Tags: opencart

trying out OC4 and journal 320rc dynamic tabs. I created a dynamic tab for one of my products, and installed an extension with the code I need.  I added the controller module name to the dynamic tab, and the controller, language and model components work fine... meaning it fetches the language file, also does a mysql query via the model module fine (I use print_r to check the sucess).  The one thing it does not do, is execute the view from the controller

$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/booking/module/booking_res2', $data));

I know that it finds the file booking_res2 because if I change to anything else it says it cannot find it.

If I add a 'return 1' in the control (just before my view call), the tab and the number one appears on the product page.

But... if the view call is made it does not display neither the tab header, nor the content - which at the moment is a literal '1' to see if it works

Has anyone come across this? I know OC4 and the journal version I have are both still new, so wondering if there might be a bug, or if I have missed anything in the documentation.

What I am trying to achieve is to have a dynamic calendar to allow customers to book accommodation in the product page.  This works great in OC3 and previous Journal.  I wanted to update for a variety of reasons, including php8, security, functionality.

Would using an event be a goer?

I use dev mode in firefox, but it doesn't give me any clues - no errors.
Any thoughts?

Comment: [SOLVED] Need add return in front $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/booking/module/booking_res2', $data));